# Getting the path name of a page who inserts a Struts tile from the inserted Struts tile

Tags: java, jsp, struts, tiles

I've got a JSP which inserts a Struts tile, which is another JSP.

Now I want to get from inside the inserted Struts tile the (path) name of the JSP which inserted that tile. I want to get the (path) name of the "uber" or "parent" JSP.

If it is, in which way is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually

> 

seems to be the solution. Since in the request is the path of the JSP actually called, that should give my everything I want.